# MySQL. How to order by order in other table

Tags: mysql

I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM '.PRFX.'sell
WHERE draft = "0" AND id
IN ( SELECT id_ FROM '.PRFX.'skipped
     WHERE uid = "'.$u.'" )
```

And I want to order by `ID field (DESC)` from `'.PRFX.'skipped'`

How to do it?

Comment: You'll have to do a JOIN of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a left join:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT * 
FROM     '.PRFX.'sell sell
JOIN     '.PRFX.'skipped skip ON skip.id_ = sell.id
WHERE    draft = "0" AND skip.uid = "'.$u.'"
ORDER BY skip.id DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ORDER BY skip.id_ DESC`?

Comment: @Andy OP says "order by ID field (DESC) from '.PRFX.'skipped'" - not sure if that's a typo or a different column.

Comment: Why left and not inner?  the AND IN makes it so that the ID must exist implying an inner and not a left.

Comment: It works, but it messes up my original sell.id. How to have it back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425911/how-to-preserve-original-id-in-join-mysql-query-operation