# How to preserve original ID in JOIN MySQL query/ operation?

Tags: mysql

I've got.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM '.PRFX.'sell sell JOIN '.PRFX.'followed follow ON follow.id_ = sell.id WHERE draft = "0" AND follow.uid = "'.$u.'" ORDER BY follow.id DESC '.$sql_limit
```

that orders table, but it messes with the original '.PRFX.'sell ID (exchanging it with the follow.id)

How to make it back to the original one?

Examples mess my original ID (from sell table) and i MUST preserve it. How to do it (Still waiting for an answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List your columns explicitly and use column aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sell.*, follow.id as followid
FROM '.PRFX.'sell sell JOIN '.PRFX.'followed follow
      ON follow.id_ = sell.id
WHERE draft = "0" AND follow.uid = "'.$u.'"
ORDER BY follow.id DESC '.$sql_limit;
```

You can add more columns in as you like.  Just be sure they have different names (which you can assign using `as`).